# using " and ' in a string

Tags: python, string

So I have this very particular problem, I'm making an enigma machine and I'm trying to encode both " and ', although I cant find a way to allow the listing of both in a single line

```
r1 = Rotor("VEADTQ8R.WUFZ5NLH 9723YP'0XOG"K4J1I,MC6SB", 0)

reflector = Reflector("EJMZALYXVBWFCRQUONTSPIKHGD1234567890 ,."'")

machine = Machine([r1], reflector)
```

I've tried using str() list() yet I cant get it to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html discusses Python's quoting rules. Short form is that you can backslash-escape characters that would otherwise be syntax to make them literal instead.

Comment: Or use triple quotes.  `'''I said, "don't!"'''`

Comment: As a quick suggestion: use triple-quoted strings (start/end with `'''` or `"""`) if your literal doesn't contain triple quotes. Otherwise, you can escape inner quotes with a backslash.

Comment: And raw, triple-quoted string (like `r"""my backslashes \ and quotes " containing ' string"""`) may also handle case when backslashes are used in the string.